# R histogram: Change label "frequency" to "Fréquence"

Tags: r, localization, label, histogram

The R command `hist(c(1,2,3,4,5), main="Titre")` produces this histogram

[image]

How can I change the label "Frequency" to "Fréquence"?

**Nota Bene:**
Despite what the answers and comments below suggest, the answer is absolutely not straightforward and instead of downvoting people should *carefully* read the documentation. Please, notice that R developers have agreed that the documentation for the `hist` command is not clear enough on that purpose and have improved it in revision r77243, after a proposal of mine.

Comment: `ylab="Fréquence"` ? (`?hist` could have been of use...)

Answer (score 0):

```
hist(c(1,2,3,4,5), main="Titre", ylab = 'Frequence')
```

This could however easily been solved by yourself with the help functions in R.

Comment: In the help for hist, the comment for ylab only reads "these arguments to title have useful defaults here." This is not that easy.